# Soft 404 problem with nginx frontend to apache2 modperl backend

Tags: apache, nginx, perl

Using nginx as a frontend to our modperl apache2 servers.

We have a soft 404 problem at Google Search Console.

The problem is that we have many pages expiring all the time, once they expire we add a noindex robots tag immediately, show a "no longer available" screen to the viewer but are unable to send a 404 header to Google as nginx sends the header and the header is a 200 as the page is served ok in its eyes.

How can I tell apache to notify nginx to send a 404 header?

Answer (score 1):

Use error_page directive and add this code:

```
  server {
      ...
      error_page 404 /404.html;
      location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        add_header Cache-Control "no-cache" always;
      }
    }
```

Comment: How would we get nginx to send the 404 after receiving the 200 from apache?

Comment: add that in error page because it adds another header.